# Facebook AccessToken

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

How to get long lived access token with **Facebook PHP SDK** (v.3.2.0) and how to set ?

We previously used `$facebook->getAccessToken();` and `$facebook->setAccessToken();` to retrieve and set access token for offline access. I don't think its working after they removed `offline_access` permissions.

So simply my question is, how to get and set long-lived access token using new **SDK** (3.2.0) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new "setExtendedAccessToken" function of the PHP SDK.

> Extend an access token, while removing the short-lived token that might have been generated via client-side flow.

```
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
```

Comment: just take a look at the php sdk code, you just call the function and the long living access token will be set. if you call getAccessToken after it, you will already have the new one.